# Expectation of a Random Function

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

x ~ N(a,b), y ~ N(c,d). x and y are independent Random Variables.

I am trying to compute this expectation:-

E[f(x,y)]..... x 
Where
f(x,y) = y if (x-y)>0
f(x,y) = x, if otherwise

The way I was thinking is

E[f(x,y)] = y*P((x-y)>0) + x*(1-P((x-y)>0))

P((x-y)>0 is something I can compute from the distributions of x and y, but E[f(x,y)] is not giving a closed form solution it's still having randomness as I still don't know what x and y can be.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the problem might become easier or the solution more obvious if you were to re-express it in terms of $U=X/b-Y/d$ and $V=X/b+Y/d$, because $U$ and $V$ are uncorrelated.  You will have to assume $(X,Y)$ have a jointly bivariate Normal distribution, because that will imply $U$ and $V$ are *independent*--and therein lies the possibility of simplification.  Please check your question for typos: for instance, "x ~ N(c,d)" most likely is intended to mean "$y \sim N(c,d)$".

Comment: @whuber - Thanks, but can you elaborate a little more with some equations if possible. I have been away from direct Mathematics for a long time so I am  bit rusty with my equations.